Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild package checkouts all .ts files in VS 2022 when I build
I have problem with Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild NUGET  package

When I build project, all typescripts files(.map files) are checkedout although there is not any changes on those files. How can I get rid of this problem?

It may be caused by certain settings or configurations. Try to refer to the following configuration:

Make sure compileOnSave is set to false and sourceMap is set to true in your tsconfig.json file.
Make sure that Microsoft.TypeScript.Default.props or Microsoft.TypeScript.targets are not individually imported in the project file. These files should be automatically imported by the NuGet package and may cause unexpected behavior if imported manually.

